# Minted NFT's using API do not apper in Metamask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, metamask, nft

So, I am doing a project - building a website that mints NFTs. I have encountered the following problem and have no idea how to fix it. My code works without any error, Metamask transaction successfully goes through yet minted NFTs do not appear in the wallet itself. Below I provide the code that is responsible for minting NFTs. If it is relevant I am developing on BSC testnet and using Flask's servers. Any help is appreciated.

script activated on button press

```
<script>
          document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            console.log("JavaScript code loaded");

            // Define a function to generate a unique metadata file for each NFT
            const account = localStorage.getItem('account');
            console.log(account);

            window.addEventListener("load", function() {
              let v = sessionStorage.getItem("account");
              if (v !== null) {
                document.getElementById("accountArea").innerHTML = `Account is: ${v}`;
              }
            });


            ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function(accounts) {
              if (accounts.length === 0) {
                sessionStorage.removeItem("account");
                document.getElementById("accountArea").innerHTML = null;
              }
            });

            const connectContract = async () => {
              const fetchContractABI = async () => {
                const response = await fetch('static/contract_abi.json');
                const json = await response.json();
                return json;
              }

              const ABI = await fetchContractABI();

              const Address = "wallet address";
              window.web3 = await new Web3(window.ethereum);
              window.contract = await new window.web3.eth.Contract(ABI, Address);
            }

            const mint = async () => {
              let name = "{{ image.title }}";
              let link = "{{ image.image_url }}";
              let price = 10 ** 15;
              let gas_price = 5 * 10 ** 9;
              let gas = 10 ** 6
              let metadataHash = "{{ image.IPFS_CID }}";
              console.log(metadataHash);
              await window.contract.methods.mint(metadataHash).send({
                from: account,
                gas: gas,
                gasprice: gas_price,
                value: price
              }, function(error) {
                if (error) {
                  window.alert("Something went wrong. Please try again later.");
                } else {
                  window.alert("Mint succesful. Check your wallet for NFT!");
                }
              });
            }

            const handleClick = async () => {
              const account = localStorage.getItem('account');
              if (!account) {
                console.log("Account not found");
                window.alert('Please connect your wallet first')
              } else {
                console.log("Uploading to Pinata...");
                var imageId = "{{ image.id }}";
                const spinner = document.getElementById('mint-loading-spinner');
                spinner.style.display = 'block';
                try {
                  console.log('Upload to Pinata successful');
                  console.log("Connecting to contract...");
                  await connectContract();
                  spinner.style.display = 'none';
                  console.log("Minting NFT...");
                  await mint();
                  console.log("Mint successful!");
                } catch (error) {
                  console.error('Request failed:', error);
                }

                spinner.style.display = 'none';

                console.log(account);
                console.log("Account found");
              }
            };
            const button = document.getElementById('send-button-{{ image.id }}');
            console.log(button);

            button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
          });
        </script>
```

Python functions responsible for minting

```
def store_image(image_title, image_url):
    current_datetime = datetime.now()
    current_datetime_string = current_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    printify_id = eshop.add_image_to_printify(image_title, image_url)
    new_image = Image(
        title=image_title,
        image_url=image_url,
        time_added=current_datetime_string,
        parent_id=current_user.id,
        printify_id=printify_id,
        IPFS_CID="none",
        is_NFT=False,
    )
    image_CID = minting.upload_to_blockchain(
        new_image.title, new_image.image_url
    )
    new_image.IPFS_CID = image_CID
    db.session.add(new_image)
    db.session.commit()
def upload_to_blockchain(title, url):
    header = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {PINATA_USER_API_KEY}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
    data = {
        "pinataOptions": {"cidVersion": 0},
        "pinataMetadata": {"name": title, "image": url},
        "pinataContent": {"image": f"{url}", "name": title},
        "sourceUrl": url,
    }
    response = requests.post(
        f"{PINATA_URL}/pinning/pinJSONToIPFS", headers=header, json=data
    ).json()
    print(f"response: {response['IpfsHash']}")
    return response["IpfsHash"]
```